# SQL Relationship Cardinality in Logical Design

Tags: sql, database-design, relationship, cardinality

I have the following issue. We are currently working on a system for a shuttle service company. Now, part of the entities in the database for this system include numerous lookup tables (such as vehicle_type, employee_status, etc), as well as some other tables, such as vehicle and vehicle_service log.

Now the issue we as a team are having is that we cannot agree on what the logical relationship cardinalities between entities should be. The two main problem relationships include the tables defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_type` (
  `type_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Store the user types - employee
 or consultant' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

which is linked to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_type` (`user_type`),
  KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `login` (`username`,`password`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Table used when logging in 
to check access level, type of user, etc. ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The `user` table includes other irrelevant data. So the issue here is that I say (because MySQL Workbench reverse engineered it that way and it makes more sense) that the relationship should be 1-many, while another team member says that it should be 0-many (because some records may exist in the `user_type` table that aren't used in the `user` table)

The other table relationship we are having words about are defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicle` (
  `vehicle_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `registration_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vehicle_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `registration_number` (`registration_number`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Actual vehicle information'
 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Again, with some other columns not relative to the question. This links with

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vehicle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `cost` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vehicle_id` (`vehicle_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Store records of all services 
to vehicles' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Should this be 1-many or 0-many because a vehicle may not yet go in for a service? According to me it should be 1-many, but I don't know if this works logically.

We are all very confused about this whole logical modelling thing, so any help would be much appreciated!

I figured it would be easier for me to create the DB first and then reverse engineer it to a physical model, but never though about logical.

Comment: What is the reason you have a compound key (`id`, and `vehicle_id`) in `service_log`? Should it not just be `id`?

Comment: yeah actually it should. My bad, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero to many if it is optional. Say for example a Sales Rep would have a zero or many customer. Why is that? Because if there is a new sales rep then it would mean he/she has no customer to begin with unless of course he/she assume the accounts of a resigned Sales Rep.

On the other hand one or many is mandatory. For example a an Order which has order date and customer who ordered should have at least one record on Order Detail table. Let's say a customer ordered a tablet last 04/22/2013 then he/she would have:

```
 Order table
 ----------------------------------------
 Orderid.  OrderDate. Customermnum
 ----------------------------------------
  1.       04/22/2013 101

 Order detail table
 ----------------------------------------
 Orderid.  Productid.  Qty.   quotedprice
 ----------------------------------------
  1.       T101       1       500
```

So, in your case User to UserType is 1 to 0 or many beacause a user type may have not been used by any user yet.

Now, vehicle to service It is also 1 to 0 or many since a vehicle may not necessarily have a service done yet.

Comment: but this is for the logical design phase only? or else this would entail having NULL-able fields?

Comment: This is more of logical design but this works both on logical design and physical design since logical design is database agnostic. Regarding NULLable field, are you referring to the related foreign key say user_type in user table? If so, it is not because the user type id is from user_type table anyway and not the other way around.